# 既存のデータをリレーションに分割したテーブルにインポートする方法

Tags: mysql

毎度お世話になっています。

今回、既存のデータをリレーションに分割したテーブルにインポートする方法を探しています。

現在はORマッパーを使用したプログラムを組んで変換してインポートするようにしてるのですが、毎回プログラムを組むのはめんどくさいです。
何か良い方法はないでしょうか。

というか皆さんこういう時どうしていますか?

エクセルで作られたデータをデータベースにインポートする時など。

Comment: どういうデータをどう分割しているかや、毎回どのくらい要件が違うかの例を共有できますか？めんどくささが具体的に伝わると解決策が集まりやすいと思います。

Comment: エクセルから出力された1テーブルのcsvをインポートしたいんです。
毎回違うのは、そもそも関連性がなくて、社員がエクセルで作ったデータを元にデータベースを作って欲しいという要望が度々あるのです。

例えばそれが、商品の情報の時もあれば、顧客情報の時もあったり、全く別物なのです。

Answer (score 1):

[「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381) の「質問と一緒に回答も提示され、さらに他の回答を期待している」に該当しそうですが。ento♦さんコメントでの情報引出し感謝です。

この問題は、結局のところ次の煩雑さが原因だと思います。

- スキーマを作るのが面倒くさい。
- 外部キーの紐付けが面倒くさい。
- (追加して)インポートのためだけにOR/Mでコード書くの面倒くさい。

とりあえず上記を前提として話を進めます。
一度「何が問題(ネック)になっているか」を考えなおして、再投稿しても良いかもしれません。

### 方法1: EXCEL側で最終的な形にする

もし最終的な格納データを、EXCEL上で作れるならば(リレーションキーの値も含め)
Integer, String, Integer
id, name, age
1, ISHII, 33
みたいな形のCSVを作ってしまって、コンバートするようなプログラムを書いたほうが楽でしょう。あるいは、VBAからODBCでMySQLへアクセスしてしまうのも手です。

一応、http://www-jp.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/ (MySQL for EXCEL)というものも存在しますが。 使ったことがないので私からは何とも言えません(軽く調べたところ。テーブル作成やスキーマ更新もできるようですが)。

### 方法2: DB側で最終的な形にする

テーブルスキーマ(CREATE TABLE)の手間はあるでしょうが
とりあえずMySQLのストレージエンジンをCSVで指定したテーブルに、ガッツリ放り込んで。
シコシコとSQLだけで済ませてしまうのも手です。
インポートした後に、user_idとか関連付けるものを追加して、
UPDATE t1, t2 SET t2.user_id t1.id WHERE ...
みたいなことやれば良いのではないでしょうか。

### 方法3: ACCESSで作れと抗議する

説明省略。

EXCELで入力されたデータが信用できなくて、データ検証もしたいという話などであれば……どのような手段であれ50歩100歩だと思います。